# $_GET does not work

Tags: php, mysql

first am listing out the product id , product name with edit and delete option .when i click on delete it should ask the option for "Yes" or "No" but its not displaying it .
Here `$_GET['deleteid']` is not working hence `echo $delid` is also not working .no error is displayed and nothing happens.

```
$product_list .= "$id - $product_name &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
<a href='inv_edit.php?pid = $id'>edit</a> |
<a href='inventory_list.php?deleteid = $id' >delete</a></br>" ;

if (isset($_GET['deleteid'])) {
    $delid = $_GET['deleteid'];
   echo $delid;
    echo 'Do you really want to delete product with ID of '.   
    $_GET['deleteid'] . '?   
    <a href="inventory_list.php?yesdelete=' . $_GET['deleteid'] . 
    '">Yes</a> | <a href="inventory_list.php">No</a>';
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Please show your code in correct format.

Comment: Show your html form.

Comment: How are you submitting the data to this? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Your code is not helping to us for anything. Please show your full code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try with this code.

```
$product_list .= "$id - $product_name &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
<a href='inv_edit.php?pid=$id'>edit</a> |
<a href='inventory_list.php?deleteid=$id' >delete</a></br>" ;
```

I have removed space like deleteid=$id instead of ?deleteid = $id.

Answer (score -2):

There is a backquote in the third line:

```
<a href='inventory_list.php?deleteid = $id' >delete</a></br>" ;`
```